# Spyder fails to launch in Anaconda on Ubuntu

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I installed Anaconda on Ubuntu 16.04 and when I want to launch spyder, I get the following error messages:

```
max@r-stats01:~$ conda install spyder
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

max@r-stats01:~$ spyder
QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":11.0".
[20523:20557:0619/163023.668325:ERROR:gl_surface_qt.cpp(229)] 
GLContextHelper::getXConfig() failed.
[20523:20557:0619/163023.668369:ERROR:gl_surface_qt.cpp(371)] 
GLContextHelper::getEGLDisplay() failed.
[20523:20557:0619/163024.293024:ERROR:gl_surface_qt.cpp(667)] 
Requested OpenGL implementation is not supported. Implementation: 0
QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current
QQuickWidget::resizeEvent() no OpenGL context
```

There seems to be an OpenGL/ graphics issue, but I don't have a clue how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error will be correctly solved in our next version (**3.3.0**) to be released in June/2019.

In the meantime, you can open a terminal and run there

`conda install pyopengl`

to get Spyder to work.

Comment: I installed that, but it still doesn't work.  Spyder loads, but it's completely black and pumping out `composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed` errors.  In my case the errors start with `libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found`, so there may be deeper issues.

Comment: This is not a problem in Spyder but with faulty graphic card drivers. You have other options though: 1) Update your Nvidia drivers; 2) Switch your default graphics card from Nvidia to Intel; 3) Use the Mesa OpenGL implementation instead of Intel or Nvidia (this depends on your Linux distro, so you need to google for it).